# Terminal stuck at top left corner and I can't move it

Tags: gnome-terminal, window

I did something to lock the terminal in the upper left hand corner of my screen.

I cannot get a response other than error messages.  Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Locked the terminal? Maybe you had it set to *Always on Top*? If you did, just right-click on its title bar and click on "Always on Top" to untick and unlock it from the desktop.

Comment: Please add those errors you get to your post as they may help us to find out where your issue is - `exit` should close your terminal.

Comment: Please give the error messages. Right now, this question is lacking information and may be closed as too localized without this info.

Comment: I have this problem as well (or at least, something that sounds the same, though I don't have error messages).   That's how I arrived here. I've updated the question to reflect what I see.  The answers below are correct for this problem.

Answer (score 16):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> or type "exit" to exit the shell. This will also close the terminal window.
2. Maybe you moved the terminal such that you can no longer see the title bar? Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then click with the left mouse button *anywhere* in the terminal window and drag it to view.

Comment: Nice answer, +1

Comment: Exiting the shell is certainly not what I was looking for, but alt-click-drag is a great trick to know: +1!

Comment: is there a more permanent solution? OR do I have to use alt+click drag every time?

Comment: Not sure why ctrl-d was listed first most people will not want to do that. Answer 2 is good.

Answer (score 0):

***Simplest Solution.***

If you can't move the (terminal) window from the top of screen:

> **Click on 'Workspace Switcher', and then move the offending window either back to the middle of that workspace or to another workspace.**

*This typically occurs if the window is somehow moved so that the top bar (of that window) is under the Ubuntu top bar.  This prevents any attempt to move the window.  (.. and is probably a GUI bug.)*