# gnome terminal locked/docked, with no window controls; Control-D ineffective

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

Not sure how I got into this situation, but a gnome terminal window has 'docked & locked' itself to the top of my screen, full width, about 20 lines deep.  There is no title bar, therefore no size controls and Control-D has no effect on it.

Thinking I was being very creative, I opened an instance emacs in that shell, searched for its pid, got its parent pid, and killed that, after which every *other* terminal window immediately closed except the one docked and locked to the top of the screen.

Could I somehow be looking at the terminal from which X was started?  It's obviously not a showstopper (rebooting solves lots of ills), but I'm curious about how I might have gotten here and what might be done to get out of a similar situation in the future.

reference closed post: [Terminal stuck at top left corner and I can't move it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194798/terminal-stuck-at-top-left-corner-and-i-cant-move-it)

Comment: You're not running [guake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guake) by any chance?

Comment: no Quake or other video games running.